# Launch a process with a different user and attach it to a Job Object

Tags: go, winapi

I have a go application running as an Administrator user on a Windows Server 2022. I need it to launch another application using a more limited user account. I also need to assign it's process to a job object.

I have found 2 possible solutions for launching an application as another user in go.

One would be getting the user token and passing it to `SysProcAttr.Token`. I tried calling LogonUser and using this token to launch the application, but I get the error `Error running app: fork/exec ./main8.exe: A required privilege is not held by the client.`

The code I tried running would be this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
    "syscall"
    "unsafe"

    "github.com/fourcorelabs/wintoken"
    "golang.org/x/sys/windows"
)

var (
    advapi32   = windows.NewLazyDLL("advapi32.dll")
    logonUserW = advapi32.NewProc("LogonUserW")
)

const (
    LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE       = 2
    LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK           = 3
    LOGON32_LOGON_BATCH             = 4
    LOGON32_LOGON_SERVICE           = 5
    LOGON32_LOGON_UNLOCK            = 7
    LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK_CLEARTEXT = 8
    LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS   = 9
    LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT        = 0
    LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT35        = 1
    LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT40        = 2
    LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT50        = 3
)

// Main entry point
func main() {
    mytoken, err := wintoken.OpenProcessToken(0, wintoken.TokenPrimary) //pass 0 for own process
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer mytoken.Close()

    fmt.Println("My Token:")
    fmt.Println(mytoken.GetPrivileges())
    fmt.Println(mytoken.GetIntegrityLevel())
    fmt.Println(mytoken.UserDetails())

    token, err := LogonUser("limiteduser", "abc")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error loging user: %s", err)
    }

    userToken := wintoken.NewToken(windows.Token(token), wintoken.TokenPrimary)

    fmt.Println("User Token:")
    fmt.Println(userToken.GetPrivileges())
    fmt.Println(userToken.GetIntegrityLevel())
    fmt.Println(userToken.UserDetails())

    cmd := exec.Command("./main8.exe")
    cmd.SysProcAttr = &syscall.SysProcAttr{
        Token: token,
    }

    out, err := cmd.CombinedOutput()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error running app: %s", err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(out))

    var s string

    fmt.Scanln(&s)
}

func LogonUser(username, password string) (syscall.Token, error) {
    pUsername, _ := windows.UTF16PtrFromString(username)
    pDomain, _ := windows.UTF16PtrFromString(".")
    pPassword, _ := windows.UTF16PtrFromString(password)

    // var handle windows.Token
    handle := uintptr(0)

    r, _, err := logonUserW.Call(
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(pUsername)),
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(pDomain)),
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(pPassword)),
        uintptr(LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE),
        uintptr(LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT),
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&handle)),
    )

    if r == 0 {
        fmt.Println("logonUserW failed: ", err)
        return 0, err
    }

    return syscall.Token(handle), nil
}
```

And the output is:

```
My Token:
[SeIncreaseQuotaPrivilege: Disabled SeSecurityPrivilege: Disabled SeTakeOwnershipPrivilege: Disabled SeLoadDriverPrivilege: Disabled SeSystemProfilePrivilege: Disabled SeSystemtimePrivilege: Disabled SeProfileSingleProcessPrivilege: Disabled SeIncreaseBasePriorityPrivilege: Disabled SeCreatePagefilePrivilege: Disabled SeBackupPrivilege: Disabled SeRestorePrivilege: Disabled SeShutdownPrivilege: Disabled SeDebugPrivilege: Disabled SeSystemEnvironmentPrivilege: Disabled SeChangeNotifyPrivilege: Enabled SeRemoteShutdownPrivilege: Disabled SeUndockPrivilege: Disabled SeManageVolumePrivilege: Disabled SeImpersonatePrivilege: Enabled SeCreateGlobalPrivilege: Enabled SeIncreaseWorkingSetPrivilege: Disabled SeTimeZonePrivilege: Disabled SeCreateSymbolicLinkPrivilege: Disabled SeDelegateSessionUserImpersonatePrivilege: Disabled] <nil>
High <nil>
Username: aminuser, Domain: MYDOMAIN, Account Type: 1 <nil>
User Token:
[SeChangeNotifyPrivilege: Enabled SeIncreaseWorkingSetPrivilege: Disabled] <nil>
Medium <nil>
Username: limiteduser, Domain: MYDOMAIN, Account Type: 1 <nil>
Error running app: fork/exec ./main8.exe: A required privilege is not held by the client.
```

I can't figure out what I am missing from this. I am guessing from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessasuserw that my application is missing the `SE_INCREASE_QUOTA_NAME` and `SE_ASSIGNPRIMARYTOKEN_NAME` privileges. But how can I assign those privileges to my own token? Or is it because the user token is missing the `TOKEN_QUERY`, `TOKEN_DUPLICATE` and `TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY` access rights? I've tried calling `DuplicateTokenEx` to set those access rights, but that didn't do anything. This is how I called that:

```
    err = windows.DuplicateTokenEx(
        windows.Token(handle),
        // 0x2000000,
        windows.STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED|windows.TOKEN_QUERY|windows.TOKEN_DUPLICATE|windows.TOKEN_IMPERSONATE|windows.TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY|windows.TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES,
        nil,
        windows.SecurityDelegation,
        windows.TokenPrimary,
        &token)
```

The other solution was calling `CreateProcessWithLogonW` instead which is suggested in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessasuserw. That worked for launching the process with another user, but then it fails to assign the process to the job object with an `Access is denied` error. Apparently, it seems that with `CreateProcessWithLogonW`, the process is created by the Secondary Logon Service which assigns the process to a job and I can't assign it to my job.

What am I missing for this to work? What else can I try?

Comment: fails to assign the process to the job object with an Access is denied error - must not. no problem do this with process started by CreateProcessWithLogonW

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you still have this issue or not, but I was working on a similar thing and found that I needed to run the source process as LOCAL SYSTEM to ensure it had the privileges it needed.

My process runs as a service so this was pretty easy to do.